# dart sdk is not configured in macos

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I already have dart sdk installed:

running `dart --version` gives me:

```
Dart SDK version: 2.17.6 (stable) (Tue Jul 12 12:54:37 2022 +0200) on "macos_arm64"
```

up until now I was using vscode but now I need to go back to android studio which gives me the following error on top of every dart file:

**Dart sdk is not configured**

N.B: This is not a fresh install. I have been using flutter and vscode in my mac for quite some time now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your Android Studio.

- Preference
- plugin
- search for flutter from the market
- install flutter and also make sure dart is install, you can confirm by searching for dart also.
- restart you android studio after and you should be fine

[image]